# Leaving the Telegram group if the bot does not have permissions or sending a message in Python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have the following code:

```
REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = [
    "can_change_info",
    "can_delete_messages",
    "can_restrict_members",
    "can_invite_users",
    "can_pin_messages",
    "can_promote_members"
]

def has_all_permissions(bot, chat_id):
    # Get the bot's member information in the group
    bot_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, bot.id)
    
    # Check if the bot has all the required permissions
    return all(getattr(bot_member, permission, False) for permission in REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)

def error_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if not update.effective_chat.type == 'supergroup':
        return
    
    # Check if the bot has the permission to send messages
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    bot = context.bot
    bot_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, bot.id)
    
    try:
        # Try to send the message about missing permissions
        missing_permissions = [permission for permission in REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS if not getattr(bot_member, permission, False)]
        missing_permissions_text = "\n".join([f"❌ {permission}" for permission in missing_permissions])
        
        update.message.reply_text(
            parse_mode='HTML'
        )
    except Exception:
        # If sending the message fails, leave the group
        if not bot_member.can_send_messages:
            bot.leave_chat(chat_id)
```

But sometimes the bot leaves just like that for some reason, and sometimes it just sends that it doesn't have permissions on commands where it doesn't need the permission at all.
what's wrong?

Comment: Probably some exception happens which you hide in `except Exception`.